# How to create a "plugin" or "block" that can manipulate Wordpress DOM in frontend?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I tried to understand [the wordpress plugin dev ecosystem](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/). It is somehow not clear what the right way is for a plugin that displays some HTML/CSS in the frontend of a wordpress/woocommerce page, that also includes javascript to manipulate the DOM or make API calls to woocommerse API?

Do I have to create a normal plugin or is it called blocks now? Is there a simple walkthrough/tutorial for such a plugin?

Comment: "Blocks" are used in the new(ish) backend editor. If you want to add a type of content to the editing screen, you might need to write a block plugin. If you need to add HTML/CSS/JS to the frontend, you'd still be writing a (non-block) plugin.

Comment: So what is it called? Because when I try to follow any resources, the Plugins are always for the Admin pages - but I want actually have something like a widget, that shows up in the frontend.. just a <h1>hi</h1><script>alert('hi');</script> would be enough.

Comment: If you're writing a custom plugin, you can call it anything you want. [WPBeginner guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/) | [WordPress Plugin Basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/) (or, if you prefer, you can hire someone to write it for you)

Comment: As written, your question is extremely broad. Without more specifics it's not possible to provide a solid recommendation. I would advise finding something in WordPress or WooCommerce core that works similarly to what you want to do and use that as a starting point. Whether that's going to involve blocks is hard to say. You mention wanting to add some HTML to a WooCommerce page. Does that mean it should be added automatically to a particular page? Or will the user choose where to place it? Should the user be able to edit the contents? What exactly does the associated script do?

Comment: I really don't understand how the question is broad. A "plugin" that shows a html button in the header of the website in the frontend (not admin pages). That is all what it should do, no functionality